# Limit editing access to a model in the Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

this is my model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('نام'), max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('نام خانوادگی'),max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(_('تصویر'),null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(_('توضیحات'),)
    created_date = jmodels.jDateTimeField(_('تاریخ ایجاد'), auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = jmodels.jDateTimeField(_('تاریخ آخرین به روز رسانی'),auto_now=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] 

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.user.email

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-updated_date']
        verbose_name = 'پروفایل'
        verbose_name_plural = 'پروفایل ها'

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

In the admin panel, I want only the profile owner and super user to have access to edit that profile

I don't know where and what changes I should make

Answer (score 0):

To implement object-level permissions, I would recommend you look at [Django Guardian](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), specifically on [admin integration](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/admin-integration.html).

Set up a [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/admin/) class for the `Profile` model as follows:

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from app_name.models import Profile

from guardian.admin import GuardedModelAdmin

class ProfileAdmin(GuardedModelAdmin):
    # Configuration done here
    pass

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Then update your `save_profile` signal to assign the user the edit permission, bearing in mind that the [default edit permission](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) for your model would be `<app_name>.change_profile`.

```py
from guardian.shortcuts import assign_perm

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        profile_obj = Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        assign_perm("<app_name>.change_profile", instance, profile_obj)
```

Have a look at the [Django Guardian docs](https://django-guardian.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/assign.html) for additional details on how to assign permissions.

Since superusers are granted all permissions by default, no additional changes would be needed to allow superusers to edit `Profile` records.